# Controlling two things with a tri-state output using discrete logic

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, tri-state, 7400

I'm trying to control a bunch of MOSFETs with an Arduino microcontroller, and was wondering if it would be possible to control two FETs with one tri-state Arduino output. There are three states that these two FETs can be in, either one on, or both off, so I don't need to ever have both on. Is there some discrete logic way to do this?  And then I'm trying to control 8 pairs of FETs.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't find that in my search. Some of those look pretty good. Here's the circuit that I just came up with: https://imgur.com/JpNUNlL

Comment: Your diode is the wrong way around. You can never pull the inverter input low. It's much better to post those details in the question rather than scattered through the comments.

Comment: Ok you're right, you can never pull the inverter input low, but if you flip it around then it'll pull the other one high. But I think I'll be able to get away with making one of the FETs a high-side P channel and making the high-Z state voltage in between the two threshold voltages.